# jquery add remove class onclick link using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

jquery add remove class onclick link using asp.net C#

```
<div class="review-footer-new">
        <p class="review-feedbackQuestion">Was this review helpful? <span class="review-feedbackLink login-required" data-rating="1">
            <span class="review-feedback-isHelpful"></span>&nbsp;Yes</span><span class="review-feedbackLink login-required" data-rating="0">
            <span class="review-feedback-isNotHelpful"></span>&nbsp;No</span></p>

    </div>


    $("p").click(function()
    {
        $("p").parent().removeClass("selected");

        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    });
```

Comment: <div class="review-footer-new">
        <p class="review-feedbackQuestion">Was this review helpful? <span class="review-feedbackLink login-required" data-rating="1">
            <span class="review-feedback-isHelpful"></span>&nbsp;Yes</span><span class="review-feedbackLink login-required" data-rating="0">
            <span class="review-feedback-isNotHelpful"></span>&nbsp;No</span></p>
       
    </div>

Comment: Explain what do you want and ask different question for different issues.

Comment: my above jquery is not working

Comment: it is just fine  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yknccLe7/1/

Comment: it seems doc ready block is missing.

Comment: or you have dynamic element so need to use event delegation

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yknccLe7/2/

Comment: when i click yes,color only change yes and when i click No,color only change No.then not select two same time

Comment: If I understand you correct I think this is what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/3Lec4750/